# angularJs directive format date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an element `<input type="date" ng-model="mydate" custom-date />` which I cannot modify.

The date right now is in format `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'`
I need to format the date to `'yyyy-MM-dd'` . How do I write a directive to format all the elements in the application with directive "custom-date "?

Aslo I know angular has date filter https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date , but I dont want to use it

Answer (score 0):

You can't change format for input type="date" fields Refer [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

**PS**: Even if you wanted, you can't use `date` filter in ngModel :)